# Python package(s) install failure on packages that requires C source compiling (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: python, pip, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio's Python, i can install packages, which as far as i know doesn't require C source compiling. When it comes to packages that requires compiling, it's always fail. My installation attempts are always done via `pip install package-name` inside the Visual Studio. This is what i have tried :

- Installing Visual Studio 2015 (VS 14.0) C/C++ Standalone compiler
- Try to re-install the package after compiler installation, still fail
- Restarting the machine, then try to re-install the package, still fail

Specifically, i have tried to install `RPIO` and `RPi.GPIO`, more or less it give similar error message :

`error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

Here is the full log from the `RPIO` installation attempt :

```
----- Installing 'RPIO==0.10.0' -----
Collecting RPIO==0.10.0
  Using cached RPIO-0.10.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: RPIO
  Running setup.py install for RPIO: started
    Running setup.py install for RPIO: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ELEMEN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-4lvb_8wu\\RPIO\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ELEMEN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-oqz8bi8d-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\RPIO
    copying source\RPIO\Exceptions.py -build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\RPIO
    copying source\RPIO\_RPIO.py -build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\RPIO
    copying source\RPIO\__init__.py -build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\RPIO
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\RPIO\PWM
    copying source\RPIO\PWM\__init__.py -build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\RPIO\PWM
    running build_ext
    building 'RPIO._GPIO' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\source
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\source\c_gpio
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files\Python36\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python36\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winrt" /Tcsource/c_gpio/py_gpio.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\source/c_gpio/py_gpio.obj
    py_gpio.c
    source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c(361): error C2373: 'setmode': redefinition; different type modifiers
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt\corecrt_io.h(528): note: see declaration of 'setmode'
    source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c(431): warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration
    source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c(431): warning C4028: formal parameter 2 different from declaration
    source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c(431): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'PyCFunction' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (__cdecl *)(int,int)'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ELEMEN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-4lvb_8wu\\RPIO\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ELEMEN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-oqz8bi8d-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ELEMEN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4lvb_8wu\RPIO\
----- Failed to install 'RPIO==0.10.0' -----
```

So am i missing something ? Or is it the package's source that missing something ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you installed Python for visual studio ?

Comment: @AkshayKathpal yes, of course.

Comment: Have you looked at the source for `py_gpio.c` to check further into what the compiler error message is complaining about? It's possible the authors never tried building it on Windows.

Comment: @martineau thank you for the hint. I've looked into the said file in the line 361 (which is hinted in the log), according to VC++ doc, *error C2373* means `The identifier is already defined with a different type modifier.` , the log also said `corecrt_io.h(528): note: see declaration of 'setmode'`, also have done it.

Turns out there is a method named setmode on both files (corecrt_io.h and py_gpio.h). Is this the problem ?

Comment: Yes, it is a problem. For some reason `py_gpio.c` is seeing two conflicting declarations of `setmode()` when it's compiled—only one can be right. That doesn't sound like a compiler version issue, but more like a bug to  me. There should be one function declaration in one included header. As I said, the authors may not have actually tried to build it on Windows, so aren't aware of the issue.

Comment: @martineau so, for now, the only practical workaround for this the problem is using another Environment / IDE / Compiler that independent from Visual C/C++ ?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it might be a possible workaround since it's an option, There's at least a couple of other free non-VC compilers available, I believe. There's probably little downside, except for the overhead of yet-another-tool in the tool-chain to maintain.

Comment: FWIW: Note that there's a POSIX standard `setmode` function should be defined in the compiler's `io.h` header, so that seems like the right header to `#include <io.h>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157937/discussion-between-tommy-aria-pradana-and-martineau) , if you may.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `py_gpio.c` is *redefining* `setmode` (line 361, used at line 431). This is a bug in their code, so you should find the team who owns it and report it to them. Most likely they added it to support older versions of MSVC, and should not add it for the current version.

It also appears that the code is using a different definition than what the C runtime has, which could later cause problems if the variable types do not match. A full code review may be needed here.

In any case, this appears to be a problem with the `RPi.GPIO` package and not with your install or the tools you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) for hinting the problems

This is not a whole solution, but rather some workaround.

**1. Use Another IDE / Tool**

While the library still not compatible with the Windows toolchain, you can try another tool or IDE that might do.

---

**2. Another library**

This is the workaround that i take. Basically, i need Python library for accessing RPi GPIO, the said `RPi.GPIO` and `RPIO` won't be installed on the Windows ver. of Python, so i move to another library called `gpiozero`. It is compatible with the Windows Python (it's successfully `pip`-ed in VS) and so far provide functionalities that i need.